# ¿Cómo enviar datos mediante data-id y mostrar el tipo de dato guardado en el menú dropdown-menu?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente `dropdown-menu` sobre la selección de monedas.

```css
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position:static;
  float:none;
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
      <div class="dropdown clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">USD
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="moneda" data-id="euro"><a href="#">EURO</a></li>
          <li class="moneda" data-id="dolar"><a href="#">USD</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Estoy enviando los datos mediante el siguiente ajax, pero no me funciona.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".moneda").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({    
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'control_moneda.php',
            Caso:'moneda',
            Id:id
            success :  function(data) { 
                $(".resultado").html(data);                              
            }
        });    
        return false; 

    });
});
```

Quiero poder activar aquí `<a href="#">USD <b class="caret"></b></a>` la moneda que este guardada en la `COOKIE` por ejemplo en esta demostración [codepen](https://codepen.io/rovalx/pen/bNQYMe?fbclid=IwAR30zDPE1OYLqcFffyGUMj7U-Nc6Z0Pye1suAhUJoxFP5TbpK1IOcFLePqA) siempre queda como principal la opción seleccionada.

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['moneda_dolar'])) {     
    echo "Modeda dolar"; 
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['moneda_euro'])) {
    echo "Moneda euro";
} else { //Por defecto.
    //Mostramos valor por defecto. 
}
```

Comment: `Caso` y `id` tienes que enviarlos con el parámetro `data` de Ajax, algo así: `data: {Caso:'moneda', Id:id }` nota que hay llaves de apertura y cierre, estás enviando un objeto con los datos dentro. Aunque imagino que `moneda` debería ser un valor dinámico, pero no veo que lo recojas en tu código.  ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano Hmmm no comprendo del todo amigo, voy a revisar con lo que me comentas :)

Comment: @A.Cedano Entonces lo estoy haciendo mal, trato de enviar esto `<li class="moneda" data-id="euro"><a href="#">USD</a></li>`

Comment: @A.Cedano No me funciono `data: {Caso:'moneda', Id:id }` creo que esa opción es para `JSON` yo estoy intentando obtener datos desde los datos `HTML` es decir tratar de enviar esto `<li class="moneda" data-id="euro"><a href="#">USD</a></li>`  al ajax.

Comment: O sea, `$.ajax` tiene varios parámetros, que son: `type, url, data`, pues para enviar contenido a Ajax tienes que usar `data`, tal y como usas `url` y `type`. En tu caso, quizá sea esto lo que se requiera: `var id = 'moneda_'+$(this).attr('data-id'); var postData={id:id};` y luego en el Ajax: `$.ajax({    
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'control_moneda.php',
            data: postData,
            success :  function(data) { 
                $(".resultado").html(data);                              
            }
        });`

Comment: En PHP, en vez usar `$_COOKIE`, deberías usar `$_POST`. La cuestión es que si esperas `$_POST["moneda_euro"]`, en el parámetro `data` de Ajax tienes que mandar valores pares parecidos a esto: `{moneda_euro:valor}`, así cuando hagas `$_POST["moneda_euro"]`, el servidor encontrará que pasaste un dato con esa clave, y el valor será lo que hayas puesto en `valor`. No sé si me explico.

Comment: @A.Cedano Anteriormente yo usaba esto https://jsfiddle.net/kvwmo0u6/ pero por cuestión del diseño intento enviar los datos mediante `<li class="moneda" data-id="euro"><a href="#">USD</a></li>` los datos se envían por método post   pero se gurda en `$_COOKIE` para evitar que el usuario realice el cambio de moneda cada vez que ingrese al sistema.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ahora se esta enviando las peticiones, pero no se están enviando los datos correctos, porque me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error `Selecciona una moneda para continuar.` , y el archivo `control_moneda.php` debe recibir estos valores `data-id="euro">` `data-id="dolar">` es decir `euro o dolar`

Comment: Es lo mismo, lo que hace tu código aquí: `var data = $(this).serialize(); ` es serializar el formulario, asociando cada `name: valor`. O sea, si hay un input nombre, lo serializa así: `nombre:'Pedro'`, es lo mismo que hacer algo como esto: `var data= {moneda_euro:valor}`, luego en PHP tienes que buscar si está la clave `nombre` para el 1er caso, o si está la clave `moneda_euro` en el 2º caso. No sé si me entiendes, se puede hacer con serialize o a mano, si lo haces a mano, tienes que poner a la izquierda de cada valor lo que sería `name` y la derecha el contenido o valor del dato.

Comment: No sé si me estás entendiendo. Más arriba te dije que crearas la variable así: `'moneda_'+$(this).attr('data-id');`, porque veo que intentas buscar el dato así en el servidor: `if ( isset($_COOKIE['moneda_dolar'])) { `, dado que en el atributo `data` lo único que tienes es la palabra `dolar` o la palabra `euro`, tienes que ponerle delante la palabra `moneda_` o cambiar la búsqueda a esto simplemente:  `if ( isset($_COOKIE['dolar'])) { `  o  `if ( isset($_COOKIE['euro'])) { ` debes entender que ese valor tiene que coincidir con lo que pongas a la izquierda de los pares en `data` de Ajax.

Comment: @A.Cedano La verdad no te comprendo, intente usar este ejemplo que me encontré https://jsfiddle.net/qhdtonpj/ pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error `Ajax Request fail`

Comment: Voy a escribir una respuesta porque en comentarios es complicado explicarse...  Ahora me lees, en la respuesta...

Comment: @A.Cedano Disculpa la molestia es todo lo que he intentado https://jsfiddle.net/qhdtonpj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax tiene un **parámetro `data`** que sirve para mandar los datos al servidor. Esos datos generalmente se mandan **en pares clave valor**. Es lo mismo que `serialize()`, cuando trabajas con formularios.

Eso que mandas es lo que el servidor buscará luego mediante `$_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE`...

Si en el servidor buscas los datos así:

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['moneda_dolar'])) {     
    echo "Modeda dolar"; 
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['moneda_euro'])) {
    echo "Moneda euro";
} else { //Por defecto.
    //Mostramos valor por defecto. 
}
```

Significa que en el parámetro `data` de Ajax, tienes que aparear los datos así:

```
{moneda_dolar: 'un eventual dato adicional'}
```

o

```
{moneda_euro: 'un eventual dato adicional'}
```

Lo que encuentra `$_COOKIE` o `$_POST` es el dato de la izquierda, y el valor del mismo es el dato de la derecha (las superglobales no son otra cosa que un array, donde la clave es el dato de la izquierda y el valor el dato de la derecha).

En tu código hay entonces dos problemas:

1. Estás mandando mal los datos en Ajax (no usas el parámetro `data`).
2. En tu HTML, el atributo `data-id` sólo tiene la palabra `euro` o `dolar`. Si tú mandas solamente eso, pero buscas en el servidor `$_COOKIE['moneda_dolar']`, el código no entrará en ese bloque, porque mandas `dolar`, pero él busca `moneda_dolar`. Yo sugeriría simplificar el código de la manera que te muestro:

   a. En Ajax mandar un par que sea así: `{moneda: valor(sea euro, dolar, etc)}`

   b. Cambiar el `$_COOKIE['moneda_dolar']` por `$_COOKIE['moneda']` y dentro determinar por su valor qué moneda ha sido posteada.

Vamos a ello:

### JS

Vamos a aplicar buenas prácticas, cambiando `document.ready` (obsoleto) por `$(function() {`; `success` (obsoleto) por `done`, `type` por `method`. Y vamos a incorporar un manejo de fallo (fail) en la petición.. He puesto un `alert`, pero lo puedes cambiar por otra cosa.

```
$(function() {
    $(".moneda").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var postData={moneda: id};

        var request = $.ajax({
            method : 'POST',
            url    : 'control_moneda.php',
            data   : postData,
            dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function(data) {
            $(".resultado").html(data);
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Ocurrió un error: " + textStatus);
        });
    });

});
```

---

### PHP

```
#NÓTESE que se busca la clave moneda, cualquier moneda, que vendrá en el valor
if ( isset($_COOKIE['moneda'])) {     
    echo "Modeda ".$_COOKIE['moneda']; 
}else{
    echo "No se posteó moneda";
}
```

Comment: se envían los datos, como le agregas un ` .done(function(data){
    }).fail(function(){
      alert( "Ajax Request fail" );
    })` al código `ajax`

Comment: @Otto ¿es una pregunta? Te mostraré como usar mejor `done` y `fail`, dado que `success` es deprecated, lo mismo que `document.ready`. Ahora te muestro.

Comment: @Otto ahí lo tienes actualizado con código conforme a jQuery 3.

Comment: Cierto lo había olvidado tengo tiempo que no pregunto o no participo he estado un poco ocupado, muchas gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Recargar la página es inevitable verdad, porque se recarga la página al dar clic en los `<li class="moneda" data-id="euro"><a href="#">USD</a></li>` eso no se puede evitar o si.

Comment: @Otto claro que sí, de hecho esa es la finalidad de Ajax y para eso está `e.preventDefault();` , ¿dices que se está recargando? No debería recargarse.

Comment: Entonces que puede estar sucediendo, porque si se recarga.

Comment: @Otto muchas veces cuando se recarga es porque hay algún error, sea en el código Javascript o en el servidor. ¿El código funciona bien? ¿Puedes revisar la consola en las opciones de Desarrollador del navegador, a ver si indica algún error?

Comment: Si el código funciona bien, ah es porque estoy usando esto `echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";` en el archivo `control_moneda.php`

Comment: @Otto no tienes que recargar nada ni redirigir a ninguna parte, Ajax se encarga de llevar y traer lo que necesites en la comunicación cliente/servidor. Existe para eso, de modo que no es necesario recargar la página sino actualizar los elementos desde el `done`

Comment: Si, lo había olvidad gracias por la ayuda :)