# Problemas al validar si repite registro en php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo problemas con un código, quiero mostrar el mensaje si el registro ya esta en la BD, osea que ya que esta repetido, si aun no existe que inserte, pero no me esta funcionando. El campo que no se debe repetir es razón social.

```
//insertar
    public function add($v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5)
{

    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('SELECT razonsocial FROM contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial=?'); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($stmt)>0) 
{ 
        echo "<p class='avisos'>El Contribuyente ya esta registrada</p> "; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contribuyentes VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    //parametro a statement
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5);

    //ejecutar el query
    $stmt->execute();
    //cerrar statement
    $stmt->close();

 }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aun no me inserta , pero con este codigo no tengo problemas , bueno no hago la comprobacion si existe o no el registro en la bd, pero funciona al insertar.

```
//insertar
    public function add($v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5)
{
    //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contribuyentes VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    //parametro a statement
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5);

    //ejecutar el query
    $stmt->execute();
    //cerrar statement
    $stmt->close();


}
```

> Estuve intentando con este codigo de javascript mostrar el mensaje si ya existe el registro , pero no pude tambien, aca comprueba si se inserta vacio y me muestra el mensaje que faltan datos.

```
    //boton guardar 
$('#guardar').on('click', function(){
    var v0 = $('#p0').val();
    var v1 = $('#p1').val();
    var v2 = $('#p2').val();
    var v3 = $('#p3').val(); //------------------------------
    var v4 = $('#p4').val(); 
    var v5 = $('#p5').val(); 
        if (v0.length>0 && v1.length>0 && v2.length>0 && v3.length>0 && v4.length>0) 
        { //valida requerido
            $('#mensaje').html('<p></p>');
            var parametros = $('#formAdd').serialize();         
            $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'contribuyente.iud.php',
                data: parametros,
                success: function(data){
                    var url = document.URL;
                    location.href = url;
                }
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#mensaje').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">Faltan cargar algunos datos!</p>');
        }
});
```

Comment: Tu query esta incompleta, necesitas igualar el campo `razonsocial` a algun valor, por ejemplo `SELECT contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial = 1`

Comment: agregando a lo que dice @alanfcm , iguala el campo `razonsocial` a la variable en la que contienes la razón social, por decir algo: `"SELECT contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial="+$v4`

Comment: $stmt=mysql_query("SELECT contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial = $v1");  hice asi, no funciona , hice algo mal? elvalor que contiente razon social es v1.

Comment: Aparte lo comentado, no es bueno mezclar tus estilos de sentencias, deberías de cambiar tu sentencia `mysql*` que está obsoleta, y usar sentencias preparadas como haces en tu siguiente sentencia `$stmt = $this->conexion->prepare...`, y veras que se soluciona. https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Lastimosamente no me esta funcionando aun.

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a dejar un posible ejemplo, aun así, también deberías de comprobar que tu *conexión* a la *Base de Datos* esté funcionando correctamente.

Como te han comentado, debes pasar un parámetro a tu sentencia `SELECT` algo así `WHERE razonsocial = parametro`.

Otro pequeño error es qué tu sentencia del `SELECT` tampoco está seleccionado tu tabla de manera correcta, fíjate que no veo tu `FROM`, debería ser algo así `SELECT razonsocial FROM contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial=?` o `SELECT COUNT(*) registros FROM contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial=?`

Tampoco es bueno mezclar tus estilos de sentencias, usa las sentencias preparadas como ya estás haciendo.

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
//insertar
public function add($v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5) {  
    //Sentencia preparada.
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('SELECT razonsocial FROM contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial=?');
    //Ligamos parametros marcadores (?)
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$tuparametro);//s si es cadena y i si es integer.
    //Ejecutar sentencia
    $stmt->execute();
    //Transfiere un conjunto de resultados desde una sentencia preparada
    $stmt->store_result();
    //Comprobamos si existe registro
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) { 
        //cerrar statement
        $stmt->close();
        //Mensaje
        echo "<p class='avisos'>El Contribuyente ya esta registrada</p> "; 
    } else { //Caso falso, no existe registro
        //cerrar statement
        $stmt->close();

        //crear statement
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contribuyentes (idcontribuyente,razonsocial,ruc,fechainscripcion,comentario,estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
           die('prepare() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->conexion->error));
        }

        //parametro a statement
        $rc= $stmt->bind_param('isissi',$v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5);
        if ( false===$rc ) {
           die('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->conexion->error));
        }

        //ejecutar el query
        $rc= $stmt->execute();
        if ( false===$rc ) {
           die('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->conexion->error));
        } else {
           //Mensaje
           echo "<p class='avisos'>El registro se inserto correctamente.</p> "; 
        }

        //cerrar statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

> Advertencia: `mysql_query*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

[`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parámetros

Una cadena que contiene uno o más caracteres que especifican los tipos para el correspondiente enlazado de variables:

**Especificación del tipo de caracteres:**

```
i   la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
d   la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
s   la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
b   la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes
```

[Manual sentencias preparadas](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Respecto al `jQuery`, te voy a dejar un ejemplo mas actualizado, aver si te funciona, personalmente no lo he probado, pero pueda que te sirva.

```
//boton guardar 
$('#guardar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var v0 = $('#p0').val();
    var v1 = $('#p1').val();
    var v2 = $('#p2').val();
    var v3 = $('#p3').val(); //------------------------------
    var v4 = $('#p4').val(); 
    var v5 = $('#p5').val(); 

    if (v0.length>0 && v1.length>0 && v2.length>0 && v3.length>0 && v4.length>0) { //valida requerido

       var parametros = $('#formAdd').serialize(); 

       var request = $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'contribuyente.iud.php',
          data: parametros,
          dataType: "html"
       });

        request.done(function(data) {
          $("#respuesta").html(data);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
           alert("Ocurrió un error: " + textStatus);
        });

     } else {
        $('#mensaje').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">Faltan cargar algunos datos!</p>');
     }
});
```

Deberías crear un div con el id con la respuesta a mostrar donde el botón de guardar.

```
<div id="respuesta"><!-- Tu respuesta PHP mediante AJAX --></div>
```

> El ejemplo `jQuery` lo cogi de esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/252426/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-datos-mediante-data-id-y-mostrar-el-tipo-de-dato-guardado-en-el-men)

Comment: @Alexis es mejor que comentas aquí o editas tu ejemplo y añades allí tu modificación, y tu siguiente error, he modificado mi ejemplo con tus columnas facilitado y he modificado la sentencia `INSERT` y el `bind_param`, intenta eliminar la columna del `id`, me imagino que en tu *Base de Datos* será *autoincrementada*.

Comment: En la tabla no uso autoincremet, autogenero el id. ultimoid+1.

Comment: @Alexis ¿La comprobación del registro funciona ahora? ¿Qué error te lanza tu `INSERT`? Me imagino que tu `id` es un *numero*, intenta modificar la `s` de cadena por `i` si fuera el caso, tambien cuenta para tu *columna estado*. Aquí te deja información: https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php , comprueba también que tus tablas están escritos correctamente. Ya que en el código a simple vista no veo ningún error.

Comment: @Alexis he modificado mi `bind_param('isissi')`, debes añadir correctamente el tipo de variable a pasar tus parámetros de marcadores, es decir, tu `PK`es un numero entero, entonces la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero `i`, te lo aclaro mejor en mi ejemplo.

Comment: Como puedo capturar los errores en las sentencias preparadas? Arriba puse un codigo que si funciona al insertar , pero no comprueba si hay datos duplicados.

Comment: @Alexis ya te he modificado mi ejemplo, para que te lanza algún error si falla tu sentencia `SQL`. Es raro que no te inserta datos, ya que no veo ningún error así a simple visto en el código, ¿qué formato tiene tu fecha? Aun así as intentado probar tu sentencia a `INSERT INTO contribuyentes VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)` como has mencionado en tu ejemplo que así si inserta y aver que sucede.

Comment: Hola,gracias por responder de nuevo, con el ejemplo que modificaste no me inserta aun, mm yo uso mozilla firefox para probar, adonde debe saltarme el error, si tengo fallas en mi sentencia? En la consola?

Comment: Si borro desde el select hasta $stmt->close(); despues del else me inserta sin problemas.

Comment: @Alexis te debería dar fallo cuando una se intenta registrar mediante el formulario en la misma pantalla del navegador si hubiera algun fallo en la sentencia, o si insertas algún registro repetido, también debe lanzarte el mensaje. ¿Ahora dices que no funciona el `insert`, pero tu `select` si funciona? ¿es decir, te manda mensaje de que el registro ya existe…?

Comment: @Alexis vi un pequeño error que se me paso :), la sentencia del `SELECT` está mal, debería ser así `$stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('SELECT razonsocial FROM contribuyentes WHERE razonsocial=?');` , como puedes ver he seleccionado la columna razonsocial y añadido el `FROM`. Espero que con esta modificación funcione correcto. Ya me comentas. Lo he actualizado en mi respuesta también.

Comment: Ahora si ya me inserta, ahi era el problema en el select, lo cambie como me mostraste, pero aun no me muestra si si hay registro duplicado o no.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('s',$v1); esta linea el $v1, si inserto un registro una razon social con el mismo nombre no me registra , eso esta bien , que no repita, solo el mensaje todavia no me muestra en pantalla.

Comment: Muchas Gracias !!  Por la ayuda amigo y por responderme mis preguntas. Si voy a crear otra pregunta.

Comment: @Alexis de nada. Así añadas más información, por ejemplo, tu formulario también etc. Suerte amigo, un saludo.

Comment: @Alexis te he añadido un ejemplo a mi respuesta de `jQery`, a ver si te funciona y te muestra el mensaje. Veras que te he creado otro mensaje de que se insertó el registro. Ya comentas.